Backward-forward algorithm for HMM
I understand the derivation of forward-backward algorithm in HMM.
However, when I try to derive a backward-forward algorithm in HMM( simply the reverse direction of original algorithm), I encountered barrier.
My first approach is Splitting P(S_{t} = k , {O_{t}} t= 1…T) into P{O_{1},…,O_{t-1}|S_{t} =k)P(O_{t},…,O_{T},S_{t} =k),
but later I figure out that this format doesn’t fit the backward and forward probability even I change the starting points of backward probability and forward probability to t-1 and t respectively.
Any thoughts on that? Thank you.

I think that this question is not related to variable selection but inference part of HMM
